# text box associated with html editor returning blank value in debugging

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0

i am adding few text boxs from code behind on a modal popup and linked a html editor to a single text box through jquery to enter detail description text. now from the front UI i am inputing the values in text boxs but in debug i see that html linked textbox is giving me blank value unlike other text boxes.

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: i have two text boxes, first is: 
private HtmlTextArea _ShortDescriptionTextArea;
second is:  
private TextBox _BodyHtmlTextBox;
//
//
i have used a jquery MCE control (html editor) and attached to _BodyHtmlTextBox text box.   
this._BodyHtmlTextBox = new TextBox();
            this._BodyHtmlTextBox.ID = "HtmlTextBox";
            this._BodyHtmlTextBox.CssClass = "MCE";
            this._BodyHtmlTextBox.Style.Add("width", "95%");
            this._BodyHtmlTextBox.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
            this._BodyHtmlTextBox.Rows = 3;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the fact you are adding serverside textboxes to the form at runtime.
I suggest adding the textboxes at design time.

Comment: actually its the projects requirement to add the controls form code behind. And exactly the same kind of functionality is implemented in different page, and some time i get the value of the text box and most of the time i dont get any value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add textboxes at runtime, I Suggest you to do it with .append() in jQuery. While for getting the values of the textbox in codebehind just make $ajax call.

Appending TextBoxes. (i.e in table)

```
    $('#myTable').append("<tr><td><input type = "text" id = 'Your ID' /></td></tr>");
```

Getting Values in CodeBehind With Ajax Call

```
    var keyword = $("[Your TextBox Id]").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'YourPage.aspx/MethodName',
        data: '{[your args]: ' + JSON.stringify(keyword) + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            //success
        },
        error: function (response) {
            // error
        }
    });
```

In Code Behind

```
    [ScriptMethod]
    [WebMethod]
    public static void MethodName(string [your args])
    {
      // grab your textbox value like this
      var value = [your args];
    }
```